# How to put the lists inside the json object and iterating at the client side?

Tags: java, jquery, json

Through jquery ajax I am calling to the sever side.In The sever side I have two list those two list I am putting into map that map in to Json Obect But its not setting.

How to itterate that two list by creating the two select box's using jquery I have used following code.

**Server Side**

```
 List<DepartmentMaster> deplist = HrDao.getDepartments();
        System.out.println("deplistdeplist" + deplist.size());
        if (!deplist.isEmpty()) {
            request.setAttribute("deplist", deplist);
        }
        List<EmployeeEntity> reportinglist = HrDao.getReportinTo();
        System.out.println("listsize" + reportinglist.size());
        if (!reportinglist.isEmpty()) {
            request.setAttribute("reportinglist", reportinglist);
        }
        Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
        map.put("deplist", deplist);
        map.put("reportinglist", reportinglist);
        System.out.println("map" + map);
        try{
        JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
        jsonobj.accumulateAll(map);
        System.out.println("jsonobj"+jsonobj);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().print(jsonobj.toString());
```

**Client Side**

```
 $("#departmentreporting").click(function() {
        $.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'getdeparmentreporting.do?', success: function(result) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                alert(obj);
                if (result !==null) {

                  $(this).closest('tr').prev('tr').after()
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am using this json-lib-2.2.2-jdk15

Comment: Why dont you use Jackson or GSON, which are much better?

Comment: How to use that one for this code

Answer (score 0):

If a valid json is returned from the server,on the client side

```
     for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
       //pick the fields of result here to do whatever you want
     }
```

Comment: I am not getting anything here can u please tell me how many jars are needed

Comment: So is your problem returning json from the server side or iterating the json returned from the server on the client side?